# How to correctly order my array of objects in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which have the weight property that contains a string with min and max weight. I need to order them from min to max and from max to min, this is my code so far but when I log in the result is not as expected. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
let arr =  [{weight : "4 - 5"}, {weight : "7 - 11"}, {weight : "20 - 25"}, {weight : "5 - 12"}, {weight : "3 - 6"}, {weight : "3 - 5"}]
let min = arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if( Number(a.weight.substring(0,2)) > Number(b.weight.substring(0,2)) && Number(a.weight.substring(5)) > Number(b.weight.substring(5))) return 1
  if( Number(b.weight.substring(0,2)) > Number(a.weight.substring(0,2)) && Number(b.weight.substring(5)) > Number(a.weight.substring(5))) return -1
  return 0
})
let max =arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if( Number(b.weight.substring(0,2)) > Number(a.weight.substring(0,2)) && Number(a.weight.substring(5)) > Number(b.weight.substring(5))) return 1
  if( Number(a.weight.substring(0,2)) > Number(b.weight.substring(0,2)) && Number(b.weight.substring(5)) > Number(a.weight.substring(5))) return -1
  return 0
})
console.log(min)
console.log(max)
```

result obtained :

```
[
  { weight: '4 - 5' },
  { weight: '3 - 6' },
  { weight: '3 - 5' },
  { weight: '7 - 11' },
  { weight: '5 - 12' },
  { weight: '20 - 25' }
]
[
  { weight: '4 - 5' },
  { weight: '3 - 6' },
  { weight: '3 - 5' },
  { weight: '7 - 11' },
  { weight: '5 - 12' },
  { weight: '20 - 25' }
]
```

like i said i my question i was expection to be sorted correctly

Comment: Note that `sort()` does not create a new array. It reorders the array that it was called on.

Comment: wouldn't you be better off organizing your data in a logical way? `let arr =  [{min: 4, max: 5}...`?

Comment: What is the "correct" sort order for overlapping min-max ranges like that?1-2,1-3,1-4,2-3,2-4,3-4?  (i.e. sort lexicographically, first by min, then by max?)